# How to create a okhttp3 Request from an HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets, okhttp

When my Java web application receives an HTTP POST request, it needs to create a new OkHttp3 Request from the HttpServletRequest and send this to another URL. The original post request could be simple form data or multi-part.

Here's the interface that I am looking to implement:

```
import okhttp3.Request;

public interface OkHttp3RequestBuilder {
    Request create(HttpServletRequest request);
}
```

Looks like the challenge boils down to how I would create an okhttp3.RequestBody. Here's the relevant part of the implementation...

```
    final HttpUrl targetUrl = HttpUrl.get("http://internal.xyz.com");

    final RequestBody requestBody = // ?????
    final Request httpRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .post(requestBody)
            .url(targetUrl)
            .build();
    return httpRequest;
```

How do I go about doing it? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, ETL! This seems to work for me:

```
@Override
public RequestBody getRequestBody(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws IOException {

    final InputStream inputStream = httpServletRequest.getInputStream();

    final byte[] requestBodyBytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);

    final String contentType = httpServletRequest.getContentType();

    final MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(contentType);

    final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, requestBodyBytes);

    return requestBody;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but `request.getReader()` must never have been called as you can call it only once.

```
Request create(HttpServletRequest request) 
{

    final HttpUrl targetUrl = HttpUrl.get("http://internal.xyz.com");

    final String originalBody = request.getReader().lines().collect (Collectors.joining (System.lineSeparator()));

    final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(request.getContentType()), originalBody);


    final Request httpRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .post(requestBody)
            .url(targetUrl)
            .build();
    return httpRequest;
}
```